# Does $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)>0$ imply $\operatorname{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)>0$ if $X$ and $Y$ are positive random variables?

Tags: probability, covariance

Does $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)>0$ imply $\operatorname{Cov}(X^2,Y^2)>0$ if $X$ and $Y$ are positive random variables?
My intuition would say yes since if $X$ increasing means $Y$ is likely to increase, then $X^2$ increasing should mean $Y^2$ is likely to increase (using the fact they are positive).

Comment: Consider the discrete distribution where each point $(i,y_i)$ is given equal probability and $(y_i) = 90, 9, 13, 17, 21, 25, 29, 33, 37, 41, 45.$

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**The answer is no:**

[image]

The idea is that $(x,y)$ (barely) have positive covariance by virtue of being linearly associated except for an outlier at the upper left.  Squaring the data greatly increases the influence of that outlier, tilting the covariance into negative territory.

(I constructed this counterexample by taking equally-spaced values of $x,$ setting $y=x,$ and then varying the leftmost value of $y.$  I recentered and rescaled the $y$ values to make them integral: from left to right, they equal $90,9,13,17,21,25,29,33,37,41,45.$)

**There is no limit to how much the covariance can change when data are squared:** absent additional information about the data (or random variables), the covariance of $(X,Y)$ tells you nothing whatsoever about the covariance of $(X^2,Y^2).$